# Retrieving Guild Version of Channel/User from DiscordSocketClient

Tags: discord.net

I need SocketGuildUser and SocketGuildChannel when a message arrives.  I don't see a straightforward way of getting these without downcasting.

```
    private void downCast(SocketMessage msg)
        {
            SocketUser user = msg.Author;
            ISocketMessageChannel channel = msg.Channel;
            var gUser = (SocketGuildUser)user;
            var Channel = (SocketGuildChannel) channel;
        }
```

Not sure under what circumstances the downcast will fail...

This all leaves me really scratching my head.  Why is there no link between a SocketMessage and a SocketGuild?  There isn't even a field for the Guild's ID to enable a subsequent call to DiscordSocketClient.GetGuild(uint64 ID).

Comment: The is no guild on a message because a SocketMessage can also come from a Direct Message (i.e. outside of a guild context). So yes, you should cast, although it would be better to soft cast with `as` so in cases where it does fail, it won't error. As stated before it would fail if it's from a DM.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  I'm only working within a guild context (and 'soft' cast match :? in F#).  I've let it run all day and everything cast according to the log file. I'd accept this as the answer if I could.

Comment: oh, I assumed C#... `user as SocketGuildUser` ... but if you are certain it's always in a guild then it fine either way.